# UIbutton stretch when clicked unexpectively

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to modify a frame work and have encountered the following problem.

I have replaced one of the button image in the framework's xib file with my own one. The image itself is approximately 20Wx20H but I have set the button size to be 40Wx40H so that the clickable area is larger than the actual image.

When the VC is displayed, I see the image to be normal 20x20 aspect ratio. However, when I clicked on the button, it stretches to 40x20 and goes back to default upon release. I was wondering if there is a UIButton parameter that I can disable which was enabled by the framework somewhere? I have done a search on the buttons in the code and could not find anything relating to stretching the button. So I am guessing somewhere in IB there is my solution?

Below are the images for the button when touch down or not touched down.

[image: button]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Also are you using autolayout? If yes, what are the constraints?

Comment: I deleted the button, and put a new one in and it worked fine now. So it must be some settings in IB. I am still curious as to which setting it was though because I inspected the settings and nothing appeared to be odd... And as far as I know, the "image" property on the UIButton should not stretch with the frame. And yes I am using autoLayout and it is 8 pixel from left right bottom edge and width/height set to 60, 40